# install_github returning error: zip file can't be opened

Tags: r, github, devtools, roxygen, roxygen2

when I run the following:

```
library(devtools)
install_github('roxygen2')
```

I get the following error:

with devtools 0.51:

```
Installing roxygen2 from hadley
Error in unzip(src, list = TRUE) : 
  zip file '/tmp/Rtmp2b44Ug/hadley-roxygen2.zip' cannot be opened
```

I installed a more recent version (0.6) of devtools: `install_github('devtools')`

and the error is more informative, but similar:

```
> install_github('roxygen')
Installing github repo(s) roxygen/master from hadley
Installing roxygen.zip from https://github.com/hadley/roxygen/zipball
Error in expand(src, list = TRUE) : 
  zip file '/tmp/Rtmp2b44Ug/roxygen.zip' cannot be opened
In addition: Warning message:
In expand(src, exdir = tempdir()) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

Am I doing something wrong?

---

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
...
```

Comment: Looks like you might not have permission to write to `/tmp/Rtmp2b44Ug` (ie in `tempdir()`) - could you check?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee I think I have permissions: the same error occurs running R as root. The Rtmp2b44Ug has been deleted, but my tmp directory has `drwxrwxrwt` permissions

Comment: Hmmm. This is a long shot, but you do have the `unzip` command on your system, right? `Sys.which('unzip')` something like `/usr/bin/unzip`?

Comment: I seem to get the same problem as you - it stems from me doing `unzip('/tmp/Rtmp2b44Ug/roxygen.zip')` (well, the `install_github` deletes that directory upon exiting, but if I do all the steps manually). The error is "Either this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive" - this seems to be a problem with the zipfile that `install_github` downloads? I'd open a bug to `devtools` on GitHub.

Comment: You want `install_github('roxygen', 'klutometis')`

Comment: Sorry for the uninformative error message - I'll work on improving that.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien the [github project](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen) is labeled "roxygen" although the [package name is roxygen2](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/blob/master/DESCRIPTION).

Comment: Thanks, I saw that and removed the comment -- just not fast enough to escape notice. FWIW, the first error in your post still might have been caused by calling `install_github(roxygen2)`, which is what you posted up there.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien `install_github('roxygen')` and `install_github('roxygen2')` give the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs because the function `install_github` sets `username='hadley'` by default (see [install-github.r source](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/R/install-github.r))

In this case, there is no github branch `hadley/roxygen`, and now download from https://github.com/hadley/roxygen/zipball/master

This will work:

```
install_github('roxygen',username = 'klutometis')
```

*note:* even though the package is called roxygen2, the "repo" name is "roxygen"

I opened a [bug in devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/72)